# Can user variables be assigned of BIT datatype?

Tags: mysql

Based on the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html):

> User variables can be assigned a value from a limited set of data types: integer, decimal, floating-point, binary or nonbinary string, or NULL value.

As you see, user variables aren't supported `BIT` datatype. Right? Ok, I have this code:

```
BEGIN
    SELECT active INTO @active FROM users WHERE id = new.user_id;
    IF (IFNULL((@active & b'100' > 0), 0) < 1) THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = "You cannot vote";
    END IF;
END
```

**Note:** `active` column is `BIT(10)`.

You know, my code surprisingly works as well .. Why? I mean how MySQL treats with `@active` variable as a `BIT` datatype?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`b'100'` is just the number `4` represented in a different way.  Similarly for the column `active` and the variable `@active`.

Comment: Look, the result of this `SELECT active INTO @active FROM users WHERE id = new.user_id; SELECT @active;` is a number like this: `1023`.  while I need to get its original bit version like this: `01111111111`. how can I  assign a bit value to a variable?

Comment: Not an issue; those are the same value, just displayed differently.  If you need to _display_ it in binary: `CONV(1023, 10, 2)`.

Comment: the display of them is important for me .. why? Because each digit of such number `0110111` means user's limitation. I mean if the first digit *(right to left)* is `1`, it means user can *vote*, if it is `0`, it means user is banned to vote. So still are you believe I don't need to use `CONV()` ?

Comment: The output from `CONV` is a character string, not a bit string.  `CONV(4, 10, 2)` is `100`, which, if used directly, would be treated as a string would convert to the number _one hundred_ (`b'1100100'`).

Comment: I don't get it honestly .. anyway upvote. Just tell my my code in the question is fine? Or should I do something? *(in the tests it works as well)*

Comment: No user --> error, not b'100' on --> error; else OK??  Perhaps this would work, too:  `IF IFNULL(( SELECT active & b'100' FROM users WHERE id = new.user_id ), 0) THEN ...`.  (Note that 0==FALSE, non-zero == true.)

Comment: If you have some free time. please take a look at [this pretty similar question](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/148143/why-the-value-changes-when-i-assign-it-to-a-variable).